# Corrupted video feed from DJI Lightbridge 2

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I am writing an android app that needs to receive video feeds from an M600, but the feed I receive from the lightbridge is corrupted (only showing some blocky pixels at the top of the frame). I have tried both the AV and HDMI inputs, with different HDMI sources and on two lighbridges. The EXT camera (secondary video feed) does work however, as does the video from a Mavic. The thing is the feed works fine in DJI Go, so this is a software issue in any case. Here's the simple callback that I use in my code:

```
mReceivedFirstVideoDataCallBack = new VideoFeeder.VideoDataCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(byte[] videoBuffer, int size) {
            if (mCodecManager != null && !isSecondFeedSelected) {
                mCodecManager.sendDataToDecoder(videoBuffer, size);
            }
        }
    };
```

Then:    `VideoFeeder.getInstance().getPrimaryVideoFeed().setCallback(mReceivedFirstVideoDataCallBack);`
I have tried to use `provideTranscodedVideoFeed()` as well instead, no difference.

And I get the same issue when running [DJI's own sample code](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-VideoStreamDecodingSample)...

[Picture of the video feed from the example app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97CDK.png). The YUV screenshots decoded with ffmpeg are producing similar results.

So am I missing something? Or is there something wrong with the SDK itself (tried updating it to 4.7.1, still no luck) and if so can it be worked around?

Edit: this is the callback I set to my SurfaceView holder:

```
SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            int videoViewWidth = mVideoSurfaceSmall.getWidth();
            int videoViewHeight = mVideoSurfaceSmall.getHeight();
            if (mCodecManager == null) {
                mCodecManager = new DJICodecManager(activity, holder, videoViewWidth, videoViewHeight);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            if (mCodecManager != null) {
                mCodecManager.cleanSurface();
                mCodecManager.destroyCodec();
            }
            mCodecManager = new DJICodecManager(activity, holder, width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if (mCodecManager != null) {
                mCodecManager.cleanSurface();
                mCodecManager.destroyCodec();
                mCodecManager = null;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: could you please show more details like how to initiate the textureView?

Comment: I'm using a SurfaceView, as I tried different things to solve the issue, but I've added the code for my initialization callback above. You can also look at the way it's done in the DJI sample I've linked since it's not working either, though iirc I had to remove the camera mode setting bit to make it work on the M600.

Answer (score 0):

@Nic please try to use `setEXTVideoInputPortEnabled()` and `setBandwidthAllocationForHDMIVideoInputPort()` to triger the right video source.
and before that make sure you have called the `setChannelSelectionMode()` method to set the selection mode to AUTO

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't make a difference. I had already tried setting these parameters through DJI Go too. In any case though I know that the right video source is enabled since I'm seeing some of it.